# How to loop through array and print out elements with a class on click in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The array has values that i want to display on the screen one by one when the div #background is clicked, but then fade out when it is clicked and produce a new element. right now it produces the elements but they dont disappear and do not fadeIn? I am working with jquery and very new to this!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var arr = ["hello", "hi", "what is up"];
        $.each(arr, function(i, val){
            $("#background").click(function(){
            var element = "<h1>" + val + "</h1>";
            $(".contain").fadeIn("slow").append(element);
            $(element).remove();
            });
      });
    });
```

Comment: you would do better with an interval in this case. Displaying the values one by one. You can do it!!

Comment: Why are you binding a new click event to each element in the array? You should reverse the logic. Bind a single click event, and the fallback function should set an interval that traverses through the array and fades each one in/out.

Comment: It looks like you're overwriting your click event with each iteration. Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Not overwriting, adding another.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the callback only once:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr = ["hello", "hi", "what is up"];
    var i = 0;
    $("#background").click(function(){
        var element = $( "<h1 style='display:none'>" + arr[i] + "</h1>" );
        $(".contain").html(element);
        element.fadeIn("slow")
        i =(i+1)  % arr.length;
    });
});
```

Html

```
<body>
<div id='background'>  <div class="contain">  click me  </div> </div>
</body>
```

Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/untuhogt/) to run the live example.

Comment: it works but it is in a new page and i can not go back and click the div to produce the next element!

Comment: @FlavioAndrade : Pls see the update of the answer. Be careful about your HTML. Everything inside `.contain` will be overwritten with the array contents.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you will show each element one at a time from the array. A counter will count the number of elements displayed in a circular manner (meaning once it is shown all the elements in the array, it will be reset to the first one). You will need the following code :

**HTML :**

```
<div id="background">
  <div class="contain">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#background {
  height: 500px;
}

.contain {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

**jQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr = ["hello", "hi", "what is up"];
  var currentKey = 0;
  $("#background").click(function() {
    //alert("CurrentKey : " + currentKey);
    $(".contain").html(" " + arr[currentKey] + " ").hide().fadeIn(600);
    if (currentKey === (arr.length - 1)) {
      currentKey = 0;
    } else {
      currentKey = currentKey + 1;
    }
  });
});
```

***You can run the snippet below to see this :***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr = ["hello", "hi", "what is up"];
  var currentKey = 0;
  $("#background").click(function() {
    //alert("CurrentKey : " + currentKey);
    $(".contain").html(" " + arr[currentKey] + " ").hide().fadeIn(600);
    if (currentKey === (arr.length - 1)) {
      currentKey = 0;
    } else {
      currentKey = currentKey + 1;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#background {
  height: 500px;
}

.contain {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background">
  <div class="contain">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's also a [JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/fftpdv3r/1/) if you prefer that.

Comment: Your code is very helpful, but everything is staying on the screen, how do you make it disappear after every new click and produce the next element in the array?

Comment: @FlavioAndrade I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question previously. You can use the `html` method instead on the append method`.

Comment: @FlavioAndrade I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: that is perfect,  I appreciate it!

Comment: @FlavioAndrade If this answer helped you, please mark it as the answer. It will be helpful to someone else who stumbles upon this.